# Display value in cell based on MAX value in another cell in same row

Tags: excel-formula, max

I am looking to do the following... Column AC has "number of copies". I want Excel to find which row has the highest number of copies, and display the Name (column B).

I'm pretty new at this, I've used the MAX function to find the highest number of copies, but I can't figure out how to display the value in column B of that row.

Thank you in advance for any help!

`=MAX(LibibData!AC:AC)` displays the highest number of copies

and `=INDEX(LibibData!B:B,MATCH(MAX(AC:AC),AC:AC,0))` displays #REF!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be missing out the sheet reference `LibibData!` which you used in `MAX()` function? i.e.

```
=INDEX(LibibData!B:B, MATCH(MAX(LibibData!AC:AC), LibibData!AC:AC, 0))
```

Comment: *whacks head against desk* Of course. Gah!! Thank you, that fixed it!!!